# No Torah = Revert to Nothingness?

Tags: sources-mekorot, torah-study, creation

Although I have [often](https://www.sefaria.org/sheets/48675.74?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) heard that the world would revert to nothingness if there wasn't someone learning Torah at any given moment, I haven't seen this written yet - what is the source of this concept?

Comment: It's also a Medrash in Esther Rabba, somewhere in the discussion of the making of the decree.

Answer (score 8):

Pesachim 68b:

> אמר רבי אלעזר אילמלא תורה לא נתקיימו שמים וארץ שנאמר אם לא בריתי יומם ולילה חקות שמים וארץ לא שמתי
>
> Rabbi Elazar said: If not for the Torah, heaven and earth would not be sustained, as it is stated: “If not for My covenant by day and by night, I would not have set up the laws of heaven and earth” (Jeremiah 33:25).

As Rashi ad. loc. explains:

> אם לא בריתי - של יומם ולילה דהיינו תלמוד תורה שכתוב בו (יהושע א׳:ח׳) והגית בו יומם ולילה:
>
> If not for My covenant - of day and night, which is study of Torah, regarding which it’s written, “And you will contemplate it day and night” (Joshua 1:8).

Comment: Whose translation is that? Where does the words "its study" come from in the Hebrew?

Comment: @DoubleAA The OP is asking about the concept that if Israel had not accepted the Torah at Har Sinai, the universe, meaning all of creation would have reverted to Tohu v’Vohu. And that acceptance wasn’t truly fulfilled until the events of Purim, קיימו מה שקבלו.

Comment: @Yaacov maybe. If he is he should state so explicitly. It certainly doesn't sound like that from what he wrote.

Comment: It would improve the question, but I suspect he doesn’t realize that’s what it is talking about. Look at what he linked to. No source or context, just a statement.

Comment: @YaacovDeane If that’s what he means I’m happy to include the Gemara in Shabbos about Yom HaShishi, but as it stands this seems to address his question sufficiently.

Comment: Does anyone know who Mordechai Lewis is, the author of the study sheet the OP linked to?

Comment: @YaacovDeane Looks like it’s [this guy](https://sassonmag.com/author/mordechailewis/). Random yeshiva bachur as the basis for a question doesn’t make a very good question.

Comment: משנה וגמרא בנדרים

Comment: @kouty I had that in an earlier draft, but the Gemara just says the same thing this Gemara does. I left it at Pesachim because that’s where this Rashi is.

Comment: @DonielF What you’re saying is not what the Rashi is saying to this page from Pesachim. Rashi quotes explicitly Yehoshua 1:8. If you actually read that posuk, it emphasizes that it is all about fulfilling the Torah. They were entering the land in order to do the mitzvot. The study is secondary & is only a vehicle which leads to doing it in actuality. That is why this question relates to Middah Keneged Middah. We fulfill and G-d fulfills. Think ‘Be fruitful & multiply’. Is it sufficient to learn about it? No! Even the mnemonic to the page brings the relationship to Purim.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Rashi explicitly says תלמוד תורה, not עשיית תורה. Granted that learning is secondary, you have to learn in order to do.

Comment: @DonielF Rashi says that G-d’s covenant is constant (day & night), meaning study Torah in which is written the posuk from Yehoshua 1:8 which emphasizes G-d’s statement that it is all in order that you do not fail to do it, to fulfill it in material, physical actions. This was the mistake of the spies we read about last week.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I don’t think we disagree on what the intent of Torah study should be. The fact is, though, Rashi does say that the ברית referred to here is תלמוד תורה.

Comment: @DonielF I emphasize that קיום התורה is not למוד התורה, except as a fallback position if you are unable to fulfill it. Think in the context of reciting the korbanot. Because we are unable to fulfill it literally now, G-d gives us a dispensation that if we recite it, He will consider it for now as if we actually did it. But when you are able to actually do it, you must do it.

Comment: Or to put it in a different context, Torah study, in particular the Oral Torah, involves speech, speaking the words of Torah. That’s literally what the blessing says, “וצונו על דברי תורה”. You don’t fulfill the mitzvah of Talmud Torah without saying the words. Thought is not sufficient. Thought is not nothing, but you must recite the words.

Comment: @DonielF You think what Rashi is emphasizing is Torah study. He’s not. He’s only giving another usage of the expression “יומם ולילה” to clarify that it means ‘constant’. G-d’s covenant to maintain the universe, that the sun comes up each day and the oceans stay in their place, etc. is constant, just like you should constantly study Torah. But קיום העולם is מדה כנגד מדה to קיום התורה, not למוד התורה. And that is the concept brought over the whole sugya to Pesachim 68b.

Answer (score 8):

The source that explicitly states this concept is the Nefesh Hachaim written by Rabbi Chaim Volozhiner, who sees it as being expressed by earlier sources. See for example [Shaar 4:25:](https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChaim.5.25.1?lang=bi)

> א**בל אם היה ח''ו העולם פנוי לגמרי אפילו רגע אחת ממש מעסק והתבוננות עם סגולה בתו''הק.** **תיכף כרגע היו כל העולמות נחרבים ונבטלים ממציאות לגמרי ח''ו.** ואף גם איש א' מישראל לבד. רב כחו. שבידו להעמיד ולקיים את כל העולמות והבריאה בכללה ע''י עסקו והתבוננותו בתו''הק לשמה. כמ''ש בחלק (צ''ט ב') כל העוסק בתורה לשמה כו'. רי''א אף מגין על כל העולם כולו. וכ''א בפ' התורה כל העוסק בתורה לשמה כו'. ולא עוד אלא שכל העולם כולו כדאי הוא לו.

Comment: Although Sefaria for some reason counts "Perakim" as Shaar 4, really it's a supplementary piece, and what they call Shaar 5 is really Shaar 4. Also, he first mentions this in [Chapter 11](https://www.sefaria.org/Nefesh_HaChaim.5.11.1).

Comment: @robev I know. I wrote it originally as 4, but someone edited it to 5.

Answer (score 1):

A source for this is Avodah zarah 3a (with steinzaltz, translation is my own):

> **ואמר** בעניין זה **ר' שמעון בן לקיש, מאי דכתיב** [מהו שנאמר]: **"ויהי ערב ויהי בקר יום הששי"** (בראשית א, לא), בה"א הידיעה? **מלמד שהתנה הקדוש ברוך הוא עם מעשה בראשית** תנאי זה, **ואמר: אם ישראל מקבלין את תורתי** בזמן מתן תורה — **מוטב, ואם לאו** [לא] — **אני אחזיר אתכם לתוהו ובוהו;**
>
> **Rabbi Shimon Ben lakish said** on this topic: **why is it written “and there was evening, and there was morning, *the* sixth day”?**" (With the added ה in הששי). **It teaches us that HaShem conditioned concerning creation** the following condition: **if Israel accepts my Torah, good, but if not, I will return you** (creation) **to *Tohu Vavohu***